# I Changed some tables, updating EDMX model some tables are "lost"

Tags: linq, visual-studio-2013

I have an SQL database with 200 tables.
I changed the primary key on one "basic" table.
I changed ALL foreign keys referring to that table, in more than 20 tables.
I Updated the LinQ model (right-click, update model from DB) to reflect the changes in the model itself.

As a result, 3 tables disappeared from the model (they are not visible in the graphical view of the model), and I get errors: Error 3013: mapping problem from line xxxx: no mapping fot table "tablename"

Trying to update again, if I look on the details of the tables to add, I can't see the 3 tables "lost": they are in the DB, I'm sure, and SEEM to be in the model, because they aren't in the list of tables that I can add, but they aren't in the model.

What could I do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

It seems solved ... one friend suggested to open manually the edmx file with an editor (I used Notepad++), and remove any reference at the 3 tables (they were there), save, and try the update again, and the tables appeared again.